# redux-form's Field can't set autoComplete off

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I want to turn off the browser's auto-complete on input field in redux-form's `Field` component, but never works. My code as follows.

```
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { TextField } from 'redux-form-material-ui';

<Field
  name="username"
  component={TextField}
  placeholder="Username"
  label="Username"
  InputProps={{ autoComplete: 'off' }} // this never works even though in the DOM's element, the attribute autocomplete="off" has already been exist
  required
  validate={[required]}
  className={classes.field}
/>
```

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Could you make it an online demo? Which may help others catch up with the problem fast.

Comment: @keikai There are so many webpack and babel configs in this, where can I provide the online demo for this?

Comment: Use `code sandbox` for example, and give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be good enough

Answer (score 0):

The actual autocomplete is applied to the basic input that is specified by `component` param. Providing that `autoComplete` prop value for the `component` will fix that issue for you.

```js
<Field
  component={(props) => (
    <TextField  
      ...
      inputProps={{ 
        ...props.inputProps, 
        autoComplete: 'no-autocomplete' 
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```